# Finding limit from Squeeze theorem: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2n-5}{3n+1}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, eulers-number-e

I recently came across a problem which stated to find the limit of an equation through the Squeeze theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2n-5}{3n+1}\right)^n$$
My approach: I did the question with L'Hospital's Rule just for the sake of finding the limit,

$$\log (L) = n(\log(2n-5) - \log(3n+1))$$
$$ \log(L) = \frac{\log(2n-5) - \log(3n+1)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
By differentiating,
$$ \log(L) = \frac{\frac{2}{2n-5}-\frac{3}{3n+1}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}$$
$$ \log(L) = -\frac{17}{12}$$
$$ L = e^{-\frac{17}{12}}$$
This was the limit obtained by me. But I wasn't able to approach through Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Are you sure of it?

Comment: Is'nt your general term $<(2/3)^n$?

Comment: $\log(L) = \frac{\frac{2}{2n-5}-\frac{3}{3n+1}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}} \implies log(L) \to - \infty$

Comment: @ab123 Oh so we can't apply L'Hospital's rule twice?

Comment: The limit is $0$.

Comment: @SahilSilare I think you can, and $\log(L) \to -\infty $ also gives $L \to 0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$0<\left(\frac{2n-5}{3n+1}\right) ^{n}<\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n,$$
so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2n-5}{3n+1}\right) ^{n}=0.$$

Comment: In determining that the limit was "$-\frac{17}{12}$" you appear to have taken the limit as n goes to 0, not infinity.

Comment: Sir can't the lower bound be $\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n}$ ?

Comment: no, when $n$ is even, $\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n}>\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$0\le\left(\frac{2n-5}{3n+1}\right) ^{n}\le\left(\frac{2n-5+5}{3n+1-1}\right) ^{n}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) ^{n}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you've tried to use L'Hopital's rule when only the denominator, not also the numerator, has $n\to\infty$ limit $0$. That's spurious. The correct analysis is $\ln L\to -\infty,\,L\to 0$ because of the asymptotic $(2/3)^n$ behaviour.

Comment: Can you clarify what's wrong with my L'Hospital rule?

Comment: @SahilSilare You can't use it with $1/0$. It's as if you tried to get the limit of $1/(1/n)$ by differentiating.